# IOS App ends with with an debugger error, just (lldb)

Tags: ios, debugging, ios-simulator, lldb

My app now runs, on the iOS Simulator, flawlessly, but on a total end of the run, the debugger just errors light blue "(lldb)". That's all' Why? and What can I do to make it not happen.

PS I have written this program using ARC-mode,

[image: This is a screenshot on the error]

If I run the simulator on it's own, my .app freezes the simulator exactly when the .app has ended and taken away from the list of running apps.

This is a screenshot of my frozen simulator

[image]

Comment: If you can reproduce the bug, try to reproduce it by running it independently from Simulator. Then you may get a crash report.

Comment: Are you stopping the app by pressing the stop button, or are you stopping it by killing it in the fast-app task bar? If you're doing the second, then the system sends a kill signal to the app, and the debugger will always trap on termination signals. Stop the app by simply pressing the 'stop' button in Xcode.

Comment: The thing I found the most disturbing is that the apps from the Apple simple codes does this type of ending without a freeze or a debugger error. Why is that? I've killed (stopped) the app by using the hardware way on simulator. I guess it's the same as "killing it in the fast bar".

Comment: It's because it's not a debugging error. The debugger received a kill signal, so it traps, but it's a system signal, not an exception. There's no error information for it to present. When you're debugging, it's bad form to kill the process like that. Stop the debugger so it can clean up happily.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the screenshot, the (lldb) debugger, the debugging info on the left side of your screenshot, and your description, I would say you have added a breakpoint somewhere and you just didn't notice it. When your code reaches a breakpoint, it immediately ceases further execution of code and brings in the debugger (in this case, lldb).

I'm almost certain that's the case.

Comment: No, he's killing the running process instead of using the debugger to stop it.

Comment: @Leonnears No mistakenly added breakpoints. However this is a screen shot of xCode right after the iOS Simulator has frozen and the lldb has stopped the iOS Simultor and posted on its screen the very helpful message "(lldb)". http://i.stack.imgur.com/nK0XO.png

Comment: @Jason Coco That is  right. I killed the process and then the lldb debugger messsage me

Comment: @johnwilund there is no message because you caused a kill signal to the app. The (lldb) is simply the console prompt because all the debugger knows is that something terminated the process it was watching unexpectedly, so it traps at the process entry point. Don't terminate apps you are debugging this way, press the stop button instead.

Answer (score 0):

go to the Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme 
and uncheck the "Debug Executable"
Good Luck